# SQLServer Query Windowing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
select 1 group_rank, 1 row_rank union all
select 1 , 2  union all
select 1 , 3  union all
select 1 , 4  union all
select 1 , 5  union all
select 2 , 1  union all
select 2 , 2  union all
select 2 , 3  union all
select 2 , 4  union all
select 2 , 5  union all
select 3 , 1  union all
select 3 , 2  union all
select 3 , 3  union all
select 3 , 4  union all
select 3 , 5  union all
select 4 , 1  union all
select 4 , 2  union all
select 4 , 3  union all
select 4 , 4  union all
select 4 , 5
```

I want to break row_rank further based upon size. If my size is 2, split the row_rank further like below. Output third column should be like below

```
select 1 group_rank, 1 row_rank, 1 batch_number union all
select 1 , 2, 1  union all
select 1 , 3, 2  union all
select 1 , 4, 2  union all
select 1 , 5, 3  union all
select 2 , 1, 4  union all
select 2 , 2, 4  union all
select 2 , 3, 5 union all
select 2 , 4, 5  union all
select 2 , 5, 6  union all
select 3 , 1, 7  union all
select 3 , 2, 7  union all
select 3 , 3, 8  union all
select 3 , 4, 8  union all
select 3 , 5, 9  union all
select 4 , 1, 10 union all
select 4 , 2, 10 union all
select 4 , 3, 11 union all
select 4 , 4, 11 union all
select 4 , 5, 12
```

As the split size is 2,

> first two rows with in the  1st group_rank gets 1st batch number,
>
> third fourth rows with in 1st group_rank gets 2nd batch number,
>
> fifth row with in 1st group_rank gets 3rd batch number,
>
> first two rows with in the  2nd group_rank gets 4th batch number,
>
> third fourth rows with in 2nd group_rank gets 5th batch number,
>
> fifth row gets with in 3rd group_rank gets 6th batch number

... and so on ..

As, I vary the split size,,, the batch number should grow or shrink accordingly.
Please provide me sql server TSQL query to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: First **you provide** what you've done so far - we'll be glad to help you fix your query - but we're not just providing all the code like that .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like simple math to me, with a little 0-based/1-based voodoo at least:

```
  ((row_number() over (order by group_rank, row_rank) - 1) / @batch_size) + 1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae029/5)

What this does is:

- `row_number() over (order by group_rank, row_rank)`: get the row number ordered over the entire set, ordered first by `group_rank` then by `row_rank`
- `- 1`: make the row numbers 0-based
- `/ @batch_size`: divide by the "batch size" you want (integer division at its best)
- `+ 1`: make the result 1-based to match your output

Comment: Thank you for giving quick response. It was very helpful. I took your suggestion and just modified very little to make it work.  ((row_number() over (order by group_rank) - 1) / @batch_size) + 1